# How to copy directory hierarchy (omitting files) into different directory?

Tags: shell

I have a directory with sub-directories I'd like to copy into a different directory. My current naive approach is like this:

```
find src_dir -type d -exec mkdir -p dest_dir/{} \;
```

It works, but makes many redundant `mkdir` calls, and also in sequence.

Have tried these as well for reference:

```
# real fast
find src_dir -type d >/dev/null
# also real fast
find src_dir -type d -exec true {} +
# slower, but not as slow as mkdir
find src_dir -type d -exec true {} \;
```

Is there a better way with less redundancy and fewer exec calls?

Comment: You want to replicate just the directory structure?

Comment: @roaima Yeah, no files. Hence `-type d`

Comment: Have you considered using `rsync`? see for example [Rsync how to include directories but not files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546001/rsync-how-to-include-directories-but-not-files)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using rsync and filtering (-f) you can filter in the directories and filter out everything else, like this:

```
rsync -av -f "+ */" -f "- *" src_dir/ new_dir/
```

Comment: I like how it fits in a single command.

Comment: Just discovered this command didn't work for me when I had multiple source directories (not shown in question, I know). foo/bar foo/baz copies bar and baz directly into dest_dir.

Comment: @Andreas, you probably missed the final `/` - try `foo/bar/ foo/baz/`.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the `;` to `+` for the `find ... -exec`, reducing the number of process calls. In this situation you need to use a little piece of shell to unroll the list of directories that will get passed in:

```
find src_dir -type d -exec bash -c 'echo cd "$0" && echo mkdir -p "$@"' dest_dir {} +
```

Remove the two instances of `echo` when you are happy that it's going to work as expected. (Note in particular that you will end up with `dest_dir/src_dir/...`; if you don't want that, use this type of construct instead, remembering to ensure that `dest_dir` is rewritten as an absolute path):

```
cd src_dir && find -type d ...
```

Comment: With GNU `find`, we can make this work even when the source directory is an absolute path: `find "$srcdir" -type d -printf "%P\\0" | xargs -0 sh -c 'mkdir -p "$0" && cd "$0" && mkdir "$@"' "$destdir"`

Comment: We don't need `mkdir -p` after the top-level destination, since Find will emit names before traversing the subdirectories.