# cp AND rsync exclude all files of all types from all subdirectories, only keep directories

Tags: find, directory, cp, file-copy

when using `find . -type d` it excludes all files whether in parent directory or in subfolders from the search. I want to extend this into a `-exec cp -p` or `rsync "{}" destination \;` so that only folders will be copied, excluding files from all folders and subfolders. I only know how to exclude by extension such as .pdf or .jpg but what if I have many multiple kinds of files and hundreds of directories? How should I approach this?

Thank you

Comment: Wouldn't a `mkdir` be easier?

Comment: an mkdir would be making a new folder with a new timestamp. I want to copy and preserve original folder timestamps as in the case of cp -p and whatever the equivalent of rsync is

Comment: one more command: `touch -r <olddir> <newdir>`

Comment: touch makes a exact duplicate of a file or folder? with its timestamps preserved and stuff..No...this would not work because as soon as touching the source file to make a duplicate file or folder, the source file/folder timestamp changes

Answer (score 1):

`find` + `mkdir` + `touch` as mentioned in the comments can work

```
find . -type d -exec sh -c 'dir="{}"; mkdir -p "destination/$dir" && touch -cr "$dir" "destination/$dir"' \;
```

The command Ipor mentioned, `touch -r <olddir> <newdir>`, takes the modification time from olddir (without changing olddir) and sets the same time on newdir. If you add `-c` you can also ensure that it does not accidental create a new file. *Must be run in source directory because it expects find to print relative paths.* And since it spawns a shell for each directory which makes it kinda slow you might prefer the alternative below.

---

Alternative:

```
cp --attributes-only -pr ./ destination && find destination -type f -empty -delete
```

The `cp` would 'copy' all files and directories recursively preserving their timestamps but not copying there content. Therefore it is fast. Not as fast as if it would be when skipping file creation but fast. The `find` then removes the empty files and leaves you with the directory structure.

Comment: Instead of a new shell for every directory, you could handle multiple results using a loop: `-exec sh -c 'for i; do …; done' sh {} +`

Comment: `find … -printf '%P\0' | xargs -0` might be a valid alternative to requiring a relative directory as start point.

Comment: Both good additions but if `rsync` is available the linked question https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/573201/573555 is probably the best solution.